# R match variables from different lists

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I want to write a loop, in which values from 3 different lists are put into another function

```
x = list(value1, value2, value3)
y = list(value1, value2, value3)
z = list(value1, value2, value3)
```

Example: function (x1, y1, z1)

I want to insert the values from the same column(x1, y1, z1 .... x3, y3, z3)of the different lists into the function. How could I do that?

Comment: `function(x[[1]],y[[1]],z[[1]])` ?

Comment: Can you show your function?

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved using e.g. `mapply`:

```r
x <- list(1, 2, 3)
y <- list(4, 5, 6)
z <- list(7, 8, 9)

mapply(function(vx, vy, vz) vx + vy + vz, x, y, z)
#> [1] 12 15 18
```

or using `purrr::pmap`:

```r
purrr::pmap(list(x, y, z), function(vx, vy, vz) vx + vy + vz)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `value1` from `x` list by using `x[[1]]`. Likewise, you get `velue3` from `y` list by using `y[[3]]`, etc.

You can then use these values in your function in various ways, depending on what your function has to do with these values.

@stefan has shown two efficient ways to do that.

If your function has to take three values from the same indices to result in a single value, such as `mean`, you can combine the list to become a matrix with three columns and three rows, so that you can apply this function to each column or each row with single index.

```
x = list(c(-3,0,2))
y = list(c(10,-1,20))
z = list(c(0.7, 0.5, 0.9))
myData = cbind(x,y,z)
myData
#      x  y   z
# [1,] -3 10 0.7
# [2,]  0 -1 0.5
# [3,]  2 20 0.9
```

To get the mean of the `value1`s :

```
mean(myData[1,])
# [1] 2.566667
```

Suppose you want to compute the means and the standard deviations of each row, you can write a function to do that

```
myfun = function(x){
 Mean = apply(x, 1, mean)
    SD = apply(x, 1, sd)
    result = rbind(Mean, SD)
 return(result)
}
```

and then apply the function to your matrix:

```
myfun(myData)
#         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
# Mean 2.566667 -0.1666667  7.633333
# SD   6.698010  0.7637626 10.723961
```

This is just an example. Many other, more efficient, ways are possible.